# Form is submitting data but sql is showing no records

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have created a simple form to submit into mysql server. When I am hitting the submit button the form is sending data, but when I check the sql database its showing no data.

Here is php code

```
<?php
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $type = $_POST['optionsRadiosInline'];
  $qty = $_POST['qty'];
  $de_add = $_POST['de_add'];
  $re_add = $_POST['re_add'];
  $sub = $_POST['sub'];
  $time_deli = $_POST['time'];
  $cost = $_POST['cost'];
  $reg_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $query = "INSERT into `orders` (user_id, type, qty, de_add, re_add, sub, time_deli, cost, reg_date) VALUES ('$type','$qty','$de_add','$re_add','$sub','$time_deli','$cost', '$reg_date')";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if($result){
    echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
  }
}else{
?>
```

Here is html form part

```
 <form role="form" name="new_order" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>User ID</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>" readonly>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Type of Dabba : </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline" id="optionsRadiosInline1" value="xl" checked>X-Large
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline" id="optionsRadiosInline2" value="l">Large
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline" id="optionsRadiosInline3" value="m">Midiam
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline" id="optionsRadiosInline3" value="s">Small
       </label>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Quantity</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="qty" placeholder="Enter text">
     </div>                       
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Destination Address</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="de_add" placeholder="Enter text">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Reciving Address</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="re_add" placeholder="Enter text">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Subscription</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="sub">
         <option>weekly</option>
         <option>Monthly</option>
         <option>Quterly</option>
         <option>Yearly</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Time</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="time">
         <option value="8.00 AM">8.00 AM</option>
         <option value="9.00 AM">9.00 AM</option>
         <option value="10.00 AM">10.00 AM</option>
         <option value="11.00 AM">11.00 AM</option>
         <option value="12.00 AM">12.00 AM</option>
         <option value="6.00 PM">6.00 PM</option>
         <option value="7.00 PM">7.00 PM</option>
         <option value="8.00 PM">8.00 PM</option>
         <option value="9.00 PM">9.00 PM</option>
         <option value="10.00 PM">10.00 PM</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <label>Cost</label>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
       <input type="text" name="cost" class="form-control">
       <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
   </form>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting? MySQL errors?

Comment: `$query = "INSERT into orders (user_id, type, qty, de_add, re_add, sub, time_deli, cost, reg_date) VALUES ('$type','$qty','$de_add','$re_add','$sub','$time_deli','$cost', '$reg_date')";` I see 9 columns but only 8 values in this query. That'd trigger an error if you'd been displaying errors. You're missing `$user_id` in your `VALUES` (or whatever variable holds the user ID)

Comment: No errors just a blank page..

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error();` after the query;

Comment: thanks @Marcus that helped. i forgot to add that on variable. thanks again.

Comment: You should add error handling to your code when you call sql queries. mysql_query() returns false if there is an error. Although, you should not be using mysql_*() functions, they are deprecated and are removed from php from v7. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: in else part you can add this: `else
{
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
    echo mysql_error($link);
}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use **mysql_*** functions, they are deprecated and removed completely in PHP 7.

Back to your question.

Your SQL query has 9 fields and 8 values. It is mismatch.

```
$query = "INSERT into `orders` (user_id, type, qty, de_add, re_add, sub, time_deli, cost, reg_date) 
VALUES ('$type','$qty','$de_add','$re_add','$sub','$time_deli','$cost', 
'$reg_date')";
```

Missing `$user_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT into `orders` (user_id, type, qty, de_add, re_add, sub, time_deli, cost, reg_date) VALUES ('$type','$qty','$de_add','$re_add','$sub','$time_deli','$cost', '$reg_date')";
```

I see 9 columns but only 8 values in this query. You're missing $user_id in your VALUES (or whatever variable holds the user ID), which is causing the query to fail (columns and values *must* be equal in number).

Comment: Guess you should get a UV as you were first to spot the issue even though someone posted an answer before you but after your comment! @Pupil That could be seen as _Vampirism_

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy!

1. In the first code fragment you did not close your "else" statement with "}"
2. The count of the fields and the count of the Values you are putting in are different, as pointed out by others
3. if you put those two lines at the start of your php script, it might help you see the errors (since most servers have them disabled by default in production)

`ini_set('display_errors', true); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

or

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

the latter one won't display notices

P.S I am subscribing to this answer so please keep me posted on how it goes!